# Django uploading a file deletes the "default" image

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have an Ourteam App that allows you to upload an image, name, title, and social media information for employees. Whenever I create an object the "default.jpg" file is deleted from the media_root.

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from smartfields import fields
from smartfields.dependencies import FileDependency
from smartfields.processors import ImageProcessor
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Employee(CMSPlugin):

    # Set Name
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=48)

    # Define Slug
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, null = False, blank = True)

    # Set Title
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=48)

    # Set Image upload path and image properties
    image_upload_path = 'ourteam/%Y/%m/%d'

    image = fields.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_path, 
        blank=True, default='ourteam/default.jpg', 
        dependencies=[
            FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
                format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 150, 'max_height': 150}))
        ])

    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=254)

    # Social Media
    twitter = models.CharField(_('twitter'), max_length=24, blank=True, default='https://www.twitter.com')
    linkedin = models.CharField(_('linkedin'), max_length=24,blank=True, default='https://www.linkedin.com')
    facebook = models.CharField(_('facebook'), max_length=24,blank=True, default='https://www.facebook.com')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('employee')
        verbose_name_plural = _('employee')
        db_table  = 'employee'
        ordering  = ('-created',)
        get_latest_by = 'created'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_all_employees():
        all_entries = Employee.objects.all().order_by('created')
        return all_entries

    def slug(sluggy):
        sluggy = sluggy.replace(' ', '-').lower()
        return slugify(sluggy)
```

Comment: Try to change the permissions for given `default.jpg` in a way that the app wont be able to delete it (`chown root` or `chmod 000`, whatever), so you will see a traceback which could help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with that :

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
# file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```